# TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x11f561b00>

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensor, tf.keras

I have a task where I am building a model and I am trying to use sequential but I ended up having an error. I am not sure what went wrong. This is just the start of the model but can't seem to work. To add more details the generator code is where I import the data and use it as an image generator. Deep code is code where I am building the model.

Deep Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)
from generators import ImageGenerator

imagegenerator = ImageGenerator(3)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu', input_shape=()))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit_generator(imagegenerator,epochs=20)
```

generator code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter
import numpy as np
import string, random
import keras

import abc
ABC = abc.ABCMeta('ABC', (object,), {'__slots__': ()})

-----
```

Comment: Aren't you mixing (i.e. using both of) `tf.keras` and `keras` modules? If yes, don't do that; just use one of them.

Comment: No i dont think so, please check my imports @today

Comment: How are you importing `Dense`?

Comment: ok i imported it like this from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from generators import ImageGenerator

Comment: @today That problem is solved by importing properly but i get image generator not an iterator error.